# Regex taking surprisingly long time

Tags: c#, regex, performance

I have a search string entered by a user. Normally, the search string is split up using whitespace and then an OR search is performed (an item matches if it matches any of the search string elements). I want to provide a few "advanced" query features, such as the ability to use quotes to enclose literal phrases containing whitespace.

I though I had hammered out a decent regex to split up the strings for me, but it's taking a surprisingly long time to execute (> 2 seconds on my machine). I broke it out to figure out just where the hiccup was, and even more interestingly it seems to occur after the last `Match` is matched (presumably, at the end of the input). All of the matches up to the end of the string match in less time then I can capture, but that last match (if that's what it is - nothing returns) takes almost all of the 2 seconds.

I was hoping someone might have some insight into how I can speed this regex up a bit. I know I'm using a lookbehind with an unbounded quantifier but, like I said, this doesn't seem to cause any performance issues until after the last match has been matched.

**CODE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegexSandboxCSharp {
    class Program {
        static void Main( string[] args ) {

            string l_input1 = "# one  \"two three\" four five:\"six seven\"  eight \"nine ten\"";

            string l_pattern =
                @"(?<=^([^""]*([""][^""]*[""])?)*)\s+";

            Regex l_regex = new Regex( l_pattern );

            MatchCollection l_matches = l_regex.Matches( l_input1 );
            System.Collections.IEnumerator l_matchEnumerator = l_matches.GetEnumerator();

            DateTime l_listStart = DateTime.Now;
            List<string> l_elements = new List<string>();
            int l_previousIndex = 0;
            int l_previousLength = 0;
            //      The final MoveNext(), which returns false, takes 2 seconds.
            while ( l_matchEnumerator.MoveNext() ) {
                Match l_match = (Match) l_matchEnumerator.Current;
                int l_start = l_previousIndex + l_previousLength;
                int l_length = l_match.Index - l_start;
                l_elements.Add( l_input1.Substring( l_start, l_length ) );

                l_previousIndex = l_match.Index;
                l_previousLength = l_match.Length;
            }
            Console.WriteLine( "List Composition Time: " + ( DateTime.Now - l_listStart ).TotalMilliseconds.ToString() );

            string[] l_terms = l_elements.ToArray();

            Console.WriteLine( String.Join( "\n", l_terms ) );

            Console.ReadKey( true );

        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**
(This is exactly what I'm getting.)

> > one
> >     "two three"
> >     four
> >     five:"six seven"
> >     eight
> >     "nine ten"

Comment: Can you write the regex without variable length look-behind? That probably is the problem. Or just write a simple parser instead of regex.

Comment: I had considered a parser, but the regex seemed simpler. All I need to do is break up the text into chunks, keeping quotes in mind. And the regex goes like the dickens until that last MoveNext() - that's the only place that takes 2 seconds.

Comment: I'd appreciate feedback from downvoters on how this question can be improved.

Comment: Can you write an expected output of the Regex query in the form of a variable dump? I can then check the expression to see if it's really doing what it needs to.

Comment: @CJxD - I've added the expected output, but I'm getting exactly what I wanted. The performance is excellent until that last MoveNext() - returning `false` - which takes in excess of 2 seconds. If the regex engine is already at the end of the input why would it take an extra 2 seconds to return `false`?

Comment: Also, are there any other varieties of input string that this Regex should match?

Comment: @CJxD - I want to match all whitespace in the input which is not enclosed within double quotes. If you can come up with a better solution, I'm all ears - but I'd still like to know why the regex is hesitating for 2 seconds (when it's alredy reached the end of the input) to return `false` on that `MoveNext()` call.

Comment: You could try this simplistic approach if you can't get yours to work: #\s+(\w+)\s+(".+?")\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+:".+?")\s+(\w+)\s+(".+?")

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try changing your regex to the following:

```
(?<=^((?>[^"]*)(["][^"]*["])?)*)\s+
```

The only change here is to put the `[^"]*` into an [atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html), which prevents the [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) that occurs.

**Note:** The regex above is obviously does not use C# regex string syntax, which I am unfamiliar with, but I think it would be the following:

```
@"(?<=^((?>[^""]*)([""][^""]*[""])?)*)\s+";
```

**Why the catastrophic backtracking occurs:**
Once all of the valid matches have been found the next match that is attempted is the space inside of the final quoted section.  The lookbehind will fail because there are an odd number of quotes before the space.

At this point the regex inside of the lookbehind will start to backtrack.  The anchor means it will always start at the beginning of the string, but it can still backtrack by dropping elements from the end of what it has matched.  Lets look at the regex inside of the lookbehind:

```
^([^"]*(["][^"]*["])?)*
```

Since the quoted sections are optional, they can be dropped as the regex backtracks.  For every chunk of non-quote characters that are not inside of a quoted section, before backtracking each character would have been matched as a part of the `[^"]*` at the beginning of the regex.  As backtracking begins on that section the last character will be dropped from what the `[^"]*` matched, and will be picked up by the outer repetition.  At this point it becomes very similar to the example in the catastrophic backtracking link above.

Comment: Excellent. Still confused though. I would have thought that the start of string assertion (`^`) would have prevented the catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: (The regex now executes in less than a millisecond, by the way. Thanks again.)

Comment: I just added some explanation on the backtracking, hopefully it makes sense but it is kind of tricky to explain.  Essentially you end up with similar behavior as `([^"]*)*`, where the nested repetition results in an exponential number of steps before the regex will fail.