# Regular expression - filename with multiple periods

Tags: java, regex, parsing

Consider the following command line: `tfile -a -fn P2324_234.w07 -tc 8811`

The regex to parse this: `-\w+|\w+\s|\w+\.+\w+\s`  (see screenshot below)

The problem is when the file name has multiple dots, say: `tfile -a -fn P23.24.23.4.w07 -tc 8811`

Question: how to ensure the `P23.24.23.4.w07` is parsed as one argument (as in `P23.24.23.4.w07`)?

[image]

Comment: Have a read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043454/using-regexes-how-to-efficiently-match-strings-between-double-quotes-with-embed). It essentially boils down to the same problem. Also, you might want to use an online tester, that supports the flavor you are actually using: http://regexplanet.com

Comment: Which part of command line you want to get ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Describe it!

```
For: P23.24.23.4.w07
use: \w+(?:\.\w+)+
```

note that for your java version you can use [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) and [atomic groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html):

```
\\w++(?>\\.\\w++)+
```

Comment: But that's an evil regex.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841970/how-can-i-recognize-an-evil-regex.

Comment: @AJMansfield no it's not. There is no overlap between `\w` and `.` which makes it pretty safe. This is called "unrolling-the-loop" and is one of *the* efficiency techniques. See the link in my comment on the question.

Comment: @AJMansfield `(a+)+` can be source of catastrophic backtracking, but (ab+)+ is not that dangerous. +1 m.buettner.

Answer (score 3):

Use a character class, e.g., `/-fn [a-z0-9.]+ -tc/i`. In English, that means "`-fn`, followed by one or more of characters between `a-z`, between `0-9`, or a `.`, followed by `-tc`." If you want to capture that part, wrap that part in parentheses.

Comment: You should probably also include underscores, and then this implifies to `[\w.]`.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this
-\w+|\w+\s|\S+.+\w+\s

Instead of 'word', we may use 'not space', You have not specified your extra requirement so I think it is fine.

[image: Regexpal testing]

Answer (score 0):

Use a quantifier:

```
-\w+|\w+\s|(?:\w+\.+)+\w+\s
           ^^^      ^^
```

You can also simply your expression to:

```
-?\w+\s?|(?:\w+\.+)+\w+\s
```

Answer (score 0):

For doing this in java, all you need to do is split it along the spaces, no regex needed.  The good ole `String.split()` should be able to handle it.