# Why does this regex make Chrome hang?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

Try typing this into Chrome's JS console. It's a regex I found to check if something's a valid URL or not:

```
"http://www.kvraudio.com/".match(/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/);
```

A match is returned, as it should be. Now try this:

```
"tp:/www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php".match(/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/);
```

Null is returned, because it doesn't match. Now..... try this:

```
"http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=5238905".match(/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/);
```

Nothing! JS appears to be dead or stuck in a loop somehow. If I use the above in an actual web page, it stops responding. Won't even scroll! Anyone got any sort of explanation for that then? What have I done wrong?!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because you have [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html):

```
([\/\w \.-]*)*
```

This expression should be modified to remove one of the stars (`*`):

```
([\/\w \.-]*)
```

Note that catastrophic backtracking typically only rears its ugly head when a match cannot be made. That's why the first example you gave executes without any issues.

Your second example exits before it hits the `([...]*)*`, so there is no opportunity for the backtracking to take effect.

For a more thorough explanation of catastrophic backtracking, see my answer to this question:
[How can I recognize an evil regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841970/how-can-i-recognize-an-evil-regex/)

Comment: Catastrophic backtracking eh?! Never heard of that one before! Thanks very much for that - sorted out the problem. Now I just need to make the expression actually match URLs properly ;)