# Why does this regular expression take a long time to run?

Tags: python, regex

The following Python code takes a long time to complete (over 5 minutes on my MacBook Pro). Am I doing something to hurt the performance of my regex?

```
import re
test = re.compile(r'< *(?:\w+ *\*? *,? *)+>')
print test.findall('if ((XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX >= XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX) && (XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX < XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX + XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)) {')
```

Comment: With `*` inside a group with `+`, I'd suspect [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Comment: Standard [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). There should be a canonical dupe, but it doesn't look like there is one.

Comment: @user2357112 - [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22205972/python-regex-takes-so-long-in-some-cases) maybe?

Comment: @user2357112 - Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982466/why-does-this-take-so-long-to-match-is-it-a-bug) one seems more thorough.

Comment: Probably you just need `< *\w+(?: *\*? *,? *\w+)*>`

Comment: Thanks everyone! Catastrophic backtracking was the issue.