# Not having parenthesis alone in a regex will prevent ReDOS?

Tags: regex, security, match, code-injection, denial-of-service

I planned to provide regex support in my service so my users can configure a regex and a String will be processed if it matches the regex.

Then I stumbled upon these articles:

[OWASP ReDOS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS)

[blog.makensi.es](http://blog.makensi.es/post/12214900786/discovering-regular-expressions-prone-to-denial-of)

And found that a simple regex can be disastrous in my servers.

I need only basic matching abilities.

I'm planning to just strip parenthesis from the regex and if it is a valid regex, it'll be processed. I believe stripping parenthesis alone will be enough to save my servers from those attacks.

Am I right in this or missing anything?

Comment: What, just yank all parentheses without even looking?  If the parens are actually needed, and you remove them, the result may be syntactically valid, but it will be a different regex.   And what will you do about parens that are escaped with backslashes, or in character classes, or both?  Are you using a regex flavor that supports non-capturing groups, atomic groups, lookaheads, lookbehinds, branch-reset groups, conditionals...?

Comment: I am trying to provide a pattern matching support. I thought I could simply use regex but found out about evil regex-es. I just wanted to know if not supporting grouping alone would prevent any evilness. But learnt from the accepted answer that it won't be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would be a naive approach and would make your server susceptible to DOS attacks.

Actually first link you have given yourself is pretty nice and complimentary to it you could look at : [How can I recognize an evil regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841970/how-can-i-recognize-an-evil-regex)

However it seems like it is a difficult task to detect such evil regexes. It depends how much risk do you want to take ? One solution could be building a mechanism to spawn processes/threads (depends on your platform) that evaluates input strings with the given regex and set a timeout for it. Once the process takes long (as long as you can afford) you could kill it.

Answer (score 1):

The risk you run is highly dependent on your specific regexp library. The classic "run-away" RE is (essentally) `aa?` repeated N times, matched against a string that is N `a`. This runs at approximately exponential time in PHP's, Python's and Perl's default libraries and roughly linear in time for Common Lisp's CL-PCRE (perl-compatible) and Go's regexp package (POSIX regular expressions).

Note that `aa?aa?aa?` has no parentheses.

Comment: This answers my question.

Also referred this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841970/how-can-i-recognize-an-evil-regex?lq=1 and found that `a{0,1000}a{0,1000}` and `a*b*[ac]*$` are evil regex-es too even though they don't have parentheses.