# Java - Multiline regex bad performance with large string

Tags: java, regex, performance

I am trying to use a multi-line regex to match all wildcards in a given source string. These strings can be in excess of 70,000 lines and each item is separated by a new line.

I seem to be experiencing huge processing times for my current regex and I can only assume that this is because it is probably poorly constructed and inefficient. If I execute the code on my phone it seems to run for an eternity.

My current regex:

`(?im)(?=^(?:\*|.+\*$))^(?:\*[.-]?)?(?:(?!-)[a-z0-9-]+(?:(?<!-)\.)?)+(?:[a-z0-9]+)(?:[.-]?\*)?$`

Valid wildcard examples:

```
*test.com
*.test.com
*test
test.*
test*
*test*
```

I compile the pattern with:

```
private static final String WILDCARD_PATTERN = "(?im)(?=^(?:\\*|.+\\*$))^(?:\\*[.-]?)?(?:(?!-)[a-z0-9-]+(?:(?<!-)\\.)?)+(?:[a-z0-9]+)(?:[.-]?\\*)?$";
private static final Pattern wildcard_r = Pattern.compile(WILDCARD_PATTERN);
```

I look for matches with:

```
// Wildcards
while (wildcardPatternMatch.find()) {
    String wildcard = wildcardPatternMatch.group();
    myProperty.add(new property(wildcard, providerId));
    System.out.println(wildcard);
}
```

Are there any changes I can make to improve / optimise the regex or do I need to look at running `.replaceAll` several times to remove all of the clutter before passing for regex matching?

Comment: Probably, moving the first lookahead after `^` will already give you a boost: [`(?im)^(?=\*|.+\*$)(?:\*[.-]?)?(?:(?!-)[a-z0-9-]+(?:(?<!-)\.)?)+(?:[a-z0-9]+)(?:[.-]?\*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/aIPq35/1)

Comment: A better pattern is [`(?im)^(?=\*|.+\*$)(?:\*[.-]?)?[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(?:\.[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*(?:[.-]?\*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/aIPq35/2). Let know if this fixes the problem

Comment: Is there one pattern per line?  If so, you can streamline things considerably by not trying to cram the whole analysis into a single regular expression.

Comment: Thanks! I will apply the change and see if if makes any difference. If it does, would you mind explaining the differences?

Comment: Each 'host' or wildcard is on a new line.

Comment: What do you mean? Does https://regex101.com/r/aIPq35/2 work? If not please explain.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you! How-come it's so much faster? I just wanted to know which changes specifically resolved the slow processing?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you need is

```
(?im)^(?=\*|.+\*$)(?:\*[.-]?)?[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(?:\.[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*(?:[.-]?\*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aIPq35/2)

Main points:

- The first lookahead should be after `^`. If it is before, the check is done before and after each char in the string. Once it is after `^`, it is only performed once at the start of a line
- The `(?:(?!-)[a-z0-9-]+(?:(?<!-)\.)?)+` part, although short, is actually killing performance since the `(?:(?<!-)\.)?` is optional pattern, and the whole pattern gets reduced to `(a+)+`, a known type of pattern that causes catastrphic backtracking granted there are other subpatterns to the right of it. You need to unwrap it, the best "linear" way is `[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(?:\.[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*`.

The rest is OK.

**Details**

- `(?im)` - case insensitive and multiline modifiers
- `^` - start of a line
- `(?=\*|.+\*$)` - the string should either start or end with `*`
- `(?:\*[.-]?)?` - an optional substring matching a `*` and an optional `.` or -` char
- `[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?` - an alphanumeric char followed with an optional sequence of any 0+ alphanumeric chars or/and `-` followed with an alphanumeric char
- `(?:\.[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*` - 0 or more sequences of a dot followed with the pattern described above
- `(?:[.-]?\*)?` - an optional substring matching an optional `.` or -`char and then a`*`
- `$` - end of a line.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks so much for taking the time to give a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest taking a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS#Evil_regexes

Your regex contains a repeated pattern:

```
(?:(?!-)[a-z0-9-]+(?:(?<!-)\.)?)+
```

Just as a quick example of how this might slow it down, take a look at the processing time on these two examples: [exact matches](https://regex101.com/r/u3HH56/1) versus having [extra characters at the end](https://regex101.com/r/u3HH56/2) and even worse, that set repeated [several times](https://regex101.com/r/u3HH56/3)

Edit: [Another good reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841970/how-can-i-recognize-an-evil-regex)

Comment: No problem, I also noticed when I looked at it that putting **, *-, -- or -* in the inputs caused it to take a long time. I'm not sure if your data would contain those strings by any chance, but it'd be worth looking changing the regex to accommodate that into if it does.