# Android slow matcher regex

Tags: java, android, regex

I have the regex here: `^([a-zA-Z]+[’',.\-]?[a-zA-Z ]*)+[ ]([a-zA-Z]+[’',.\-]?[a-zA-Z ]+)+$`

When I run the code bellow:

```
Pattern namePattern = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z]+[’',.\\-]?[a-zA-Z ]*)+[ ]([a-zA-Z]+[’',.\\-]?[a-zA-Z ]+)+$");
Matcher namelMatcher = namePattern.matcher("hau hauhahahahahjdjdj);
```

And lost very long time to complete. Why the regex match slow? Any suggestion how to improve this?

Comment: Do you mean to have a forward slash at the beginning and end of your regex?

Comment: @jrahhali I have updated and removed them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest taking a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS#Evil_regexes

Your regex contains several repeated patterns:

```
([a-zA-Z]+[’',.\-]?[a-zA-Z ]*)+
```

and

```
([a-zA-Z]+[’',.\-]?[a-zA-Z ]+)+$
```

Just as a quick example of how this might slow it down, take a look at the processing time and steps on these examples: [a few characters](https://regex101.com/r/WmdtSP/1) versus having [even more characters at the end](https://regex101.com/r/WmdtSP/2) and even worse, that set repeated [many times](https://regex101.com/r/WmdtSP/3)

To fix this, you should try narrowing down your regular expressions a bit depending on what you're actually trying to grab, and remove some of the recursion in them. Without knowing more about your desired input/output it's kind of hard to guess what you want, but I'd wager something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/WmdtSP/4) would accomplish the same thing faster:

```
^([a-zA-Z’',.\-]+) ([a-zA-Z’',.\-]+)$
```

or more inclusively

```
^([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)$
```

[Another good reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841970/how-can-i-recognize-an-evil-regex)

Comment: Thank you, you're right. I have updated my regex : `^([a-zA-Z]+[\'\,\.\-]+[a-zA-Z ]+) ([a-zA-Z]+[\'\,\.\-]+[a-zA-Z ]+)$` and faster