# In the realm of Regular Expressions, what is backtracking?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

The expression I have is

`\((from \/projects(\/(\w|.)+)+):$(\d+\))`

The strings I'm trying to match are:

```
(from /projects/idpro/branches/release_2018/test/test/test.1:13118)
(from /projects/idpro/trunk:13074)
```

the online regex testing utility I'm using blows up stating `catastrophic backtracking`. So here I am trying to learn what backtracking is, so I can avoid it and fix my code.

Of the 2 string examples I have provided, I would like to match both. In the first case, I'm trying to match `(from /projects`. After the word `projects`, I want to ignore a path of any dept, so long as the string ends with a `:\d+\)`

Similarly, for the second example, I want a match if `(from /projects` is followed by at least one `folder`, and ends with a `:\d+\)`.

AdThanksVance

Comment: A great Google search expression is [regex backtracking explained](https://www.google.com/search?q=regex+backtracking+explained)

Comment: Your code will work just fine if you remove the `$` sign. https://regex101.com/r/PUv8Ma/1/

Comment: @Ibrahim You're right...apologies.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's ok, I was just trying to understand your point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I recognize an evil regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841970/how-can-i-recognize-an-evil-regex)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what is causing the catastrophic backtracking.  But in any case, I would phrase your regex as this:

```
^\(from \/projects(?:\/[^\/]+)*:\d+$
```

As you can see in the demo below, there is no catastrophic backtracking happening.

### Demo

Catastrophic backtracking is usually associated with poorly written regex patterns.  So, just don't do that, and it probably won't happen.