# Validate user-provided regex to avoid ReDoS attacks

Tags: php, regex, security

Is there a way to validate a user-provided regex pattern to avoid Regex Denial-of-Service (ReDoS) or arbitrary code execution attacks, assuming that also the subject (second argument of preg_match) is user-provided? I would like to use it like below:

```
<?php
function executeRegex($userProvidedRegex, $userProvidedInput) {
   return preg_match($userProvidedRegex, $userProvidedInput);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I recognize an evil regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841970/how-can-i-recognize-an-evil-regex)

Comment: What try/catch is there for `*.*?*))` ? Does this stop your php screept ?

Comment: @Booboo I can't find an answer for my question... I need some code example.

Comment: @sln my problem is about detecting not only formally valid regex, but malicious regex expressions that can use all my resources.

Comment: The answer to the post I referenced says in part *Catastrophic backtracking in modern regex engines is similar in nature to the halting problem which Alan Turing proved was impossible to solve.* There is no perfect algorithm for solving your problem.

Comment: RE2 doesn't support backtracking.  It's more robust than PCRE

Comment: @erik258 unfortunately I could not find it available for PHP except for an abandoned project.