# How to trigger a RegexMatchTimeoutException in a unit test

Tags: c#, regex, unit-testing, xunit

Sonar Qube analysis recommended adding a time out to this validation logic to prevent Regex backtracking.

Then Sonar Qube complained that the catch `RegexMatchTimeoutException` was not tested.

What is the best way to trigger the exception in an Xunit test so that coverage can be maintained?

I have tried passing absurdly long strings into the function in an attempt to get it to throw an exception but nothing seems to work.

```
public bool Validate(string s, string pattern)
{    

    bool result;

    try
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(s, pattern, RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10)))
        {
            result = true;
        }
    }
    catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException)
    {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841970/how-can-i-recognize-an-evil-regex , it might be worth to try a `^((ab)*)+$` regex on string like `abababababababababababab a` (with even larger first part ab...ab)