# lookahead in the middle of regex doesn't match

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string `$s1 = "a_b";` and I want to match this string but only capture the letters. I tried to use a lookahead:

```
if($s1 =~ /([a-z])(?=_)([a-z])/){print "Captured: $1, $2\n";}
```

but this does not seem to match my string. I have solved the original problem by using a `(?:_)`instead, but I am curious to why my original attempt did not work? To my understanding a lookahead matches but do not capture, so what did I do wrong?

Comment: What is wrong with `if($s1 =~ /([a-z])_([a-z])/){print "Captured: $1, $2\n";}` ?

Comment: Logically, your match does not work. From the point where you look ahead, the next instruction ensures there should *never* be an underscore.

Comment: Yes the regex says find a letter followed by a character that is both an underscore and a letter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A lookahead looks for next immediate positions and if a true-assertion takes place it backtracks to previous match - right after `a` - to continue matching. Your regex would work only if you bring a `_` next to the positive lookahead `([a-z])(?=_)_([a-z])`

You even don't need (non-)capturing groups in substitution:

```
if ($s1 =~ /([a-z])_([a-z])/) { print "Captured: $1, $2\n"; }
```

### Edit

*In reply to @Borodin's comment*

I think that moving backwards is the same as a backtrack which is more recognizable by debugging the whole thing (Perl debug mode):

```
Matching REx "a(?=_)_b" against "a_b"
.
.
.
   0 <> <a_b>                |   0| 1:EXACT <a>(3)
   1 <a> <_b>                |   0| 3:IFMATCH[0](9)
   1 <a> <_b>                |   1|  5:EXACT <_>(7)
   2 <a_> <b>                |   1|  7:SUCCEED(0)
                             |   1|  subpattern success...
   1 <a> <_b>                |   0| 9:EXACT <_b>(11)
   3 <a_b> <>                |   0| 11:END(0)
Match successful!
```

As above debug output shows at forth line of results (when 3rd step took place) engine consumes characters `a_` (while being in a lookahead assertion) and then we see a backtrack happens after successful assertion of positive lookahead, engine skips whole sub-pattern in a reverse manner and starts at the position right after `a`.

At line #5, engine has consumed one character only: `a`. Regex101 debugger:

[image]

How I interpret this backtrack is more clear in this illustration (Thanks to @JDB, I borrowed his [style of representation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37979580/1020526))

```
a(?=_)_b
*
|\
| \
|  : a (match)
|  * (?=_)
|  |↖
|  | ↖
|  |↘ ↖
|  | ↘ ↖
|  |  ↘ ↖
|  |   : _ (match)
|  |     ^ SUBPATTERN SUCCESS (OP_ASSERT :=> MATCH_MATCH)
|  * _b
|  |\
|  | \
|  |  : _ (match)
|  |  : b (match)
|  | /
|  |/
| /
|/
MATCHED
```

By this I mean if lookahead assertion succeeds - since extraction of parts of input string is happened - it goes back upward (back to previous match offset - (`eptr` (pointer into the subject) [is not changed but offset is](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_exec.c#L1585-L1591)) and while resetting consumed chars it tries to continue matching from there and I call it a backtrack. Below is a visual representation of steps taken by engine with use of [`Regexp::Debugger`](https://metacpan.org/release/Regexp-Debugger)

[image]

So I see it a backtrack or a *kind of*, however if I'm wrong with all these said, then I'd appreciate any reclaims with open arms.