# Lookaround backtracks right before closing bracket

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

<sub>Note: this question is an outcome from [**another answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39321555/1020526) that as of now all its comments are removed.</sub>

In case of using a lookaround construct within a RegEx there is a backtrack or a *kind of* that takes place right before closing bracket. As I'm aware this backtrack comes to output of Perl and PCRE debuggers:

[image]

The question is what is this *backtrack*, why is it there and how is it interpreted as a [backtrack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backtrack is a lie.

It's just a consequence of how the regex101 debugger is implemented. It uses a PCRE feature (flag) called `PCRE_AUTO_CALLOUT`. This flag tells the PCRE engine to invoke a user-defined function at *every* step of matching. This function receives the current match status as input.

The catch is that PCRE *doesn't* tell the callout when it *really* backtracks. Regex101 has to infer that from the match status.

As you can see, in the step before the *"backtrack"* occurs, the current matched text is `a_`, and just after you get out of the lookahead, it's reverted to `a`. Regex101 notices the matched text is *shorter* and therefore it infers that a backtrack *must have happened*, with the confusing outcome you noticed.

---

For reference, here's the internal PCRE representation of the pattern with auto-callout enabled:

```
$ pcretest
PCRE version 8.38 2015-11-23

  re> /a(?=_)_b/DC
------------------------------------------------------------------
  0  59 Bra
  3     Callout 255 0 1
  9     a
 11     Callout 255 1 5
 17  17 Assert
 20     Callout 255 4 1
 26     _
 28     Callout 255 5 0
 34  17 Ket
 37     Callout 255 6 1
 43     _
 45     Callout 255 7 1
 51     b
 53     Callout 255 8 0
 59  59 Ket
 62     End
------------------------------------------------------------------
Capturing subpattern count = 0
Options:
First char = 'a'
Need char = 'b'
```

As you can see, there's no branching opcode there, just an `Assert`.

Comment: It's not only regex101 (PCRE and Python) debugger that shows it as a backtrack step but Perl debugger does it too. What about them?

Comment: @revo Perl is a different engine, but it all boils down to *how* you define what a backtrack is. If you define it as "go back in the matched string", then yes, a backtrack occurs. If you define it as "try some other alternative", then what occurs is just an assertion ending. My guess is that the definition was guided by the implementation (it was probably just easier to go with the first definition).

Comment: I know that, that's why I point to it as a *kind of* backtrack in question. If it is call out that's the culprit then Perl should have a difference that has not.

Comment: @revo: *"Perl debugger does it too"* I mentioned this before: I don't see any reference to "backtracking" in the Perl re debug output. What makes you think it's there?

Comment: Sorry but you didn't mention that before. Re-check `Regexp::Debugger` output for a clear representation of what is going on. @Borodin

Comment: @revo: Ah I see. It says *Back-tracked within regex and reend of positive lookahead*. I don't understand *reend* but I see your point.

Comment: I don't get it either. @Borodin

Comment: @revo: I raised this with the module's author, Damian Conway, who replied with this *"It's a bug in the automatic description generation. I've just patched it and uploaded a new release that changes the message to* ***Resetting match position after end of positive lookahead*** *which is much more descriptive"*

Comment: @Borodin nice, that description makes sense

Comment: This is now *entirely* something different. Did you send an email? I appreciate your effort on this. @Borodin

Comment: In case of a lookbehind it shows such description: *Back-tracked within regex and retrying a literal '_' character* What do you think about this? @Borodin

Comment: @revo: What is your exact regex and target string? I think that may be another error that the author may want to fix. I'll get in touch again.

Comment: It doesn't differ, in my case it is `/a_(?<=_)b/` @Borodin

Comment: @revo: Well that's different from the forward look-ahead: it clearly has to be. I just wanted a definitive expression to discuss, and I guess that's `'a_b' =~ /a_(?<=_)b/`. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your comment. @Borodin

Comment: I'm questioning *"It doesn't differ"* as we have never discussed the look-behind construct at all.

Comment: In question I'm asking about lookarounds (both lookaheads and lookbhinds). You asked about exact regex that I'm pointing to, and I said it doesn't differ. Whole regex could be something different. It only needs a lookbehind inside it for `Regexp::Debugger` to produce a similar description. Am I clear? @Borodin

Comment: @revo: Okay, I think you mean "it doesn't matter". "It doesn't differ" means "it isn't different".

Comment: Yea, I could say that but I think we were just thinking about a different subject. Nevermind. @Borodin