# regex to extract number and date from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract date, percentage or number from string. Strings can be:

1. the response value 10 (from here I want to extract 10)
2. the response value 10/12/2014 (from here I want to extract 10/12/2014)
3. the response value 08/2015 (from here I want to extract 08/2015)

I've written regex as `(?:\d{2}\/\d{4}|\d{2}(?:\/\d{2}\/\d{4})?)` Regex is satisfying 12/12/2014, 10, 02/2012.

I'm also trying to modifying same regex to get 10, 08/2015 and 10/10/2015 but not getting how to get.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Could you provide a list of values you want to match? Your current regex does not match `12/12/2014` as you claim, to match `12/12/2014`, you'd need `(\d{2})[\/](\d{2})[\/](\d{4})`

Comment: You could use an alternation to match all 3 formats `\b(?:\d{2}\/\d{4}|\d{2}(?:\/\d{2}\/\d{4})?)\b` https://regex101.com/r/xqApkK/1 Note that 4 digits also match 9999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match  your example data, you could use an alternation matching either 2 digits / 4 digits, or match 2 digits with an optional part that matches 2 digits and 4 digits.

```
\b(?:\d{2}\/\d{4}|\d{2}(?:\/\d{2}\/\d{4})?)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary, prevent the word char being part of a larger word
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\d{2}\/\d{4}` Match 2 digits/4 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{2}` Match 2 digits
  - `(?:\/\d{2}\/\d{4})?` Optionally match /2 digits/4 digits
- `)` Close group
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xqApkK/1)

**Note** that 2 and 4 digits could also match 99 and 9999. If you want to make your match more specific, this page can be helpful https://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html

```js
const pattern = /\b(?:\d{2}\/\d{4}|\d{2}(?:\/\d{2}\/\d{4})?)\b/;
[
  "the response value 10",
  "the response value 10/12/2014",
  "the response value 08/2015"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.match(pattern)[0]));
```

Comment: I'm thinking, would `\b(?:(?:\d\d\/){1,2}\d{4}|\d\d)\b` be a good alternative? What are your thought on that? I'm not yet familiar enough with regex to tell difference in performance of nested non-capture groups.

Comment: @JvdV That is shorter :-)

Comment: If so, feel free to use it. Otherwise Ill post it as an alternative. I've also read somewhere that `\d\d` would beat `\d{2}` in performance. What are your thoughts on that? Not sure if this is where I should ask you these things. But I find it interesting =)

Comment: @JvdV From the top of my mind I would not know. Engines can also pre optimize the pattern, so the number of steps is not always a performance guarantee. Most of the times I look at the data, and check what is the least amount of work, so not to trigger the engine if you know upfront that is will not give a match. This page has some interesting information about optimizations https://www.rexegg.com/regex-optimizations.html Also IMHO the book Mastering Regular Expressions chapter 4 - 6 contain nice information about that.

Comment: I also believe the same when it comes to steps as the only benchmark(they are useful but not always). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37979155/7571182) post might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun (regex is fun) an alternative to the accepted answer:

```
\b(?:(?:\d\d\/){1,2}\d{4}|\d\d)\b
```

See the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xqApkK/2)

- `\b` - Match a word boundary.
- `(?:` - 1st Non-capturing group.

  - `(?:` - 2nd Non-capturing group.

    - `\d\d\/` - Match two digits and a literal forward slash.
    - `){1,2}` - Close 2nd non-capturing group and use it once or twice.
  - `\d{4}` - Match four digits.
  - `|` - Alternation (OR).
  - `\d\d)` - Two digits and close 1st non capturing group.
- `\b` - Match a word boundary.

---

[image]

---

Maybe we can do this even without alternation:

```
\b\d\d(?:(?:\/\d\d){1,2}\d\d)?\b
```

See the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xqApkK/3)

- `\b` - Match a word boundary.
- `\d\d` - Match two digits.
- `(?:` - 1st Non-capturing group.

  - `(?:` - 2nd Non-capturing group.

    - `\/\d\d` - Match a literal slash and two digits.
    - `){1,2}` - Close 2nd non-capturing group and use it once or twice.
  - `\d\d` - Match two digits.
  - `)?` - Close 1st non-capturing group and make it optional.
- `\b` - Match a word boundary.

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Match method supports regExp and will return an array with the items you are looking for:

```js
var date = "12/12/2014"

 var arr = date.match(/(\d{2})[\/](\d{2})[\/](\d{4})/);

 console.log(arr[0]);
 console.log(arr[1]);
 console.log(arr[2]);
 console.log(arr[3]);
```