# C# Regular Expression taking too much time

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regular expression i.e.

```
[A-Z]\w*(\s+([A-Z0-9]\w*|-[a-z]?|and|or|of|of the))*(?=\s*,?\s*\(?\s*as defined below\s*\)?)
```

and it is working fine for me for running it on a word document. But changing it to

```
[A-Z]\w*(\s*([A-Z0-9]\w*|-[a-z]?|and|or|of|of the))*(?=\s*,?\s*\(?\s*as defined below\s*\)?)
```

with just changing **\s+** to **\s*** takes too much time. and does not return the result even in 10 minutes(waiting more than that is quite vain). even

```
[A-Z]\w*(\s([A-Z0-9]\w*|-[a-z]?|and|or|of|of the))*(?=\s*,?\s*\(?\s*as defined below\s*\)?)
```

also not giving result in less than 10  minutes.

Moreover i am testing it for

```
Registration Rights has agreed not to
 exercise such rights until after expiration of the Lock-Up Period (as defined below)
```

and expecting `Lock-Up Period` as result

Comment: Check this qn http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499764/regex-taking-surprisingly-long-time

Comment: Let's first clarify if this is a C# related problem or catastrophic backtracking. Test on an external system for example http://regexr.com

Comment: You should not make that whitespace pattern optional. It will lead to catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: The regular expression you shared is invalid. Please share your *real* regex.

Comment: its updated now. yupe, there were some typo mistakes.

Comment: About your first pattern, you say that "it is working fine for me", but then you state that you expect a match of `Lock-Up Period`, but the first pattern matches only `Up Period`.  You can't get good help if you aren't careful about the details you post.

Comment: @CPerkins yupe i think i didint communicate well. Actually problem is first regex is not capturing `Lock-Up Period` because of one space limitation. I want to make whitespace optional. The whole problem is just with whitespace.

Comment: Okay, so you selected the Parallel programming answer already.  Did that really fix the problem?

Comment: actually that helped a bit. i just wait for that thread to complete its working. but i think performance can be an issue in future. still looking for some solid answer. Moreover, i am putting  my regex in a template and then matching from that template. @CPerkins do you have any answer?

Comment: `private static string asDefinedBelow = @"my regex here";`  and    `internal static SearchTemplate TermUseAsDefinedBelow = new SearchTemplate(asDefinedBelow, ArtifactType.TERMUSEASDEFBELOW, false);`   are written in Patterns.cs and using it as   `artifacts = Search.SimpleSearch(_textUnits, Patterns.TermUseAsDefinedBelow, reporter.Children[1]);` in another class.

Comment: So do you have access to the actual code which creates and calls the `Regex` object, perhaps inside call to `SimpleSearch()`?  Also, do you know if `SearchTemplate()` changes or adds to the original pattern you specify in `asDefinedBelow`?  This is important, because in my initial testing of your pattern, the time and success of the pattern depended upon the tool I used to run it and what options I selected, like "Ignore Pattern Whitespace" or "Compiled", etc.  If I run a simple test in c#, calling the Regex.Test or Regex.Match directly, it is successful and returns in milliseconds.

Comment: i just changed it to below regex and its working fine. Thanks for your cooperation.
`[A-Z][\w-]*(\s+((of the|of|and|or)\s+)?[A-Z0-9][\w-]*)*(?=\s*,?\s*\(\s*as\s+defined\s+below\s*\))`

Comment: @CPerkins please add this answer below and i will mark it. i cant add any answer for the time due to other issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try use Parallel programming it will shift working load on all available cores.
Put your code in a method and call that method from parallel like``

```
Parallel.Invoke(() => DoSomeWork(), () => DoSomeOtherWork());
```

See
[Parallel Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992634(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Why is this an acceptable answer for debugging a regular expression?  Simply placing a faulty regex in another thread doesn't solve the problem.